# Аппроксимация, интерполяция и экстраполяция функции, заданной таблицей данных

Tags: математика, теория, интерполяция

Нужно написать программу, которая аппроксимирует график функции по таблице ее значений и использовать при этом критерий наименьшей ошибки. Есть формула для вычисления этого критерия? Из какой области программирования или математики данная тема?

Чтобы не вводить в заблуждение, дословное задание:

> 1. Ввод данных из файла *.txt
> 2. Выбор наилучшего метода аппроксимации по критерию наименьшей ошибки
> 3. Построение графиков по исходным данным, по результатам аппроксимации и графика ошибки
> 4. Интерполяция и экстраполяция за границами диапазона исходных данных
> 5. Вывод результатов на форму и в файл *.html.

Что такое критерий наименьшей ошибки? И график ошибки?

Comment: "строит график функции по таблице ее значений" - если вы строите график по точкам, то откуда тут взяться ошибке?

Comment: @Kromster если график строить только по точками, то получится ломанная.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH вам нужны функции сглаживания графиков(аппроксимации)? Как вариант можно здесь посмотреть http://scask.ru/a_book_tp.php?id=80

Comment: @АртемЧерепахин вовсе не обязательно. Не стоит играть в телепатов, пока ТС не уточнит вопрос )